# Ideas to improve this query indexes

Tags: mysql

I feel like the following query is too slow:

```
(1679.1ms)
SELECT  `media_files` . * 
FROM  `media_files` 
INNER JOIN  `playlist_media_files` ON  `media_files`.`id` =  `playlist_media_files`.`media_file_id` 
WHERE  `media_files`.`type` 
IN (
'AudioFile'
)
AND  `playlist_media_files`.`playlist_id` =7
ORDER BY media_files.artist ASC , media_files.release_year ASC , media_files.album ASC , media_files.disc_number ASC , media_files.position ASC
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type   | possible_keys                                                                         | key                                       | key_len | ref                                                     | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | playlist_media_files | ref    | index_playlist_media_files_on_playlist_id,index_playlist_media_files_on_media_file_id | index_playlist_media_files_on_playlist_id | 4       | const                                                   | 3782 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | media_files          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_media_files_on_type                                                     | PRIMARY                                   | 4       | mydb.playlist_media_files.media_file_id                 |    1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Every column is indexed.
Any MySQL expert can tell how can it be improved by looking at the explain?

The multiple ORDER BY is killing the performance.

Edit: removed private URLs from comments

Update: it seems I can do something like `concat(..fields..) AS sort` for a late ORDER BY sort.

Comment: How many rows in each table and what is the index cardinality? `SHOW INDEXES FROM tablename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query you would probably benefit from having a composite index on `(playlist_id,media_file_id)` in the `playlist_media_files` table, which would let mysql to use only this index to know which row to read from `media_files` without having to read actual data from `playlist_media_files` to see what is the value of `media_file_id` for every row that satisfies `playlist_id = 7` condition (a lot of them do).

You should see additional `using index` for the first row of explain output.

Mysql would still have to create temporary table to sort it by so many columns, but sorting 4k rows in memory is not so expensive.

So basically try:

```
ALTER TABLE `playlist_media_files` 
  ADD INDEX `playlist_media_composite` ( `playlist_id` , `media_file_id` ) ;
```

and see the results.

Edit: I tried to simulate the same problem on my test db, creating the same tables and filling them with random 400k rows using php, trying to get similar index cardinality.
Without composite index the same query has following execution plan:

```
1   SIMPLE  playlist_media_files    ref     playlist_id,media_file_id   playlist_id     4   const                                       3925    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  media_files             eq_ref  PRIMARY                     PRIMARY         4   test.playlist_media_files.media_file_id     1       Using where
```

And the average result is about:

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 2,702 total, Query took 0.0359 sec)
```

After adding the composite index and doing `ANALYZE TABLE playlist_media_files` explain shows:

```
1   SIMPLE  playlist_media_files    ref     playlist_id,media_file_id,playlist_media_composite  playlist_media_composite    4   const                                       3925    Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  media_files             eq_ref  PRIMARY                                             PRIMARY                     4   test.playlist_media_files.media_file_id     1       Using where
```

And the average result:

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 2,702 total, Query took 0.0176 sec)
```

However in both cases sorting was done in memory (and still creating tmp table and sorting takes 80% of the time here) and looking at your profiling screenshot most of the time is lost on copying temporary table to disc. Thats where the difference comes from. My tables have only columns required for this query, and probably my random strings weren't as long as yours, while you have a lot more columns and you are selecting all of them, sorting only on few. So your temporary table doesn't fit in the memory and obviously doing things on disc has to be a lot slower.

So your main focus here should be either on increasing buffer sizes to accomodate your big select or limiting number of columns to select that maybe you don't need that much.

Comment: I remember having this composite key and removed it to do some tests, adding back this key however yield no noticeable performance gains, it is still taking 1775.3ms

Comment: Is it used in explain? What's your mysql ver?

Comment: You also select * from media_files, any column blob there by chance? It's quite unusual to have 4k rows unable to fit in memory. Can you post `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for both tables?

Comment: the problem is really the multiple order by, I'm not sure there's a solution to this. without ORDER BY the query is blazing fast.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I already tried to select only the fields I need, but yes, it's definitely the order by. a LIMIT does not even apply too much because it will be executed against the temporary table, so not really a point here. I'll try to play with mysql settings, even if it's harder in managed environments. Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the meaning of the orderbys? Using it in more than one variable just doesn't make sense in this case.
Why not just order by one thing?
You might be having problems with database design normalization, are you familiar with that?

Comment: I'd like to have an initial representation of the data to pass already sorted to an underlying JSON parser for display purpose. That's why it's sorted this way.